# Wallsit - Any Benefit to the Wall?

Tags: core, quads

Is there any reason to do wallsits on a wall if you can do them without with perfect form?

It seems like not using a wall would achieve the same thing with more stabilization (assuming you can bend forward like in a squat, but still keep your spine neutral)

Comment: It would be nearly impossible to do a "perfect form" wallsit without a wall. Your center of gravity would be too far behind your support to be able to stay upright.

Comment: @JohnP Sure - I am asking if you lose anything by bending forward at the hips (like during a squat), while still keeping a neutral spine. It seems to me like you don't.

Comment: But that isn't perfect form, then. I would edit that part out of your question and make it clear you are changing the form of the exercise. Perfect form in a wallsit is angles of 90 and 90.

Comment: What's the benefit of the 90 degree at the hips though?

Comment: what are you trying to achieve by doing wallsits?

Comment: @aaaaaa Knee stability when doing thinks like squats and pistol squats.

Comment: i guess you should rephrase question. Something like "I want to improve my X, i heard wallsits are good for that. Unfortunately i have no walls at my disposal, what i can do instead?"

Comment: @aaaaaa "I have no walls at my disposal" - hue, hue. The thing is - I like wallsits, but I want to make them even more challenging.

Comment: my intention wasn't to be cheeky, but to help you ask a goal-oriented question. It would be like saying, hey I want big butt but only willing to do X. How to make X more challenging, since i don't want to do squats?

Comment: @aaaaaa I do squats and deadlifts already - I just really feel the wallsits without the instability I feel when I squat heavy - the wallsits also help my squats. I realize its strange and the answer is to just do squats.

Comment: If your goal is bigger squat, there are useful variations such as paused squat

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The squat and the wall-sit both are done for different purposes. You could mix them, but that could mean diluting the individual advantages of each. Try doing a wall-less sit of the kind you describe, you will feel very different pain in your muscles compared to a wall-sit. Also, the time you can hold each will be different. That should be a signal that the body mechanics are quite different.

A wall-sit is done primarily to strengthen the quadriceps, isolating them from other muscles. The straight back helps in the isolation, so that the glutes don't come into play. By maintaining the 90-90, my personal observation/feeling is that the hamstrings are also not worked. This isolation helps to build the quads, or rehabilitate them after injury. Since a single muscle is worked and the joints are stationary, you will generally feel an intense burning feeling in the thigh. This is the quads getting worked.

The squat position is more compound, it works the glutes, hamstrings, hip adductors, and the quads too, though not primarily.

In conclusion, if your goal involves massive, strong quads (think cycling, horse-riding, skiing), or you are recovering from an injury, the wall is your friend. For general fitness, a compound form, especially with movement (squat) is more balanced and has greater benefits.